# Potential issues davening while wearing a mask

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, chazzan-prayer-leader

I understand the potential benefits of wearing a mask, but I was wondering if any halachic issues have arose from wearing a mask.
For instance, the chazzen and the baal korei have to have clear voices.
Not being able to smell bsamim could be a bracha v'tala.
Making kiddush.

Comment: See Shaarei Ephraim Shaar 3:4 regarding covering one's mouth during krias HaTorah (not during a pandemic)

Comment: Are you just looking for lists of things that might be issues, or issues with rabbinic treatments of how to deal with them properly?

Comment: Has any rabbanan raised an issue with covering one's face while davening?